# SSRS SORTING OF MONTH COLUMN IN MATRIX

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created a report in SSRS by using matrix. I gave column as Months.
But the months are displaying in sorted format. I want it in normal form like from Jan to Dec..

Comment: It's really not very clear what you mean - can you show us what "sorted format" and "normal form" actually look like on screen? Do you mean you're seeing month numbers (1, 2, 3 etc.) and you want instead month names ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar" etc.)?

Comment: I have inserted Matrix in ssrs .Then under column i gave data as 'Months'.

Comment: What does "I gave data as Months" mean? You added a field called Months from a Dataset to your Matrix? Again, if you just showed us what you mean, it would be a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780598/sorting-by-year-and-monthname)? The answer may resolve your question here too.

Comment: By adding a new field which maps the month name into numeric value, I got  correct output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field of month's number and use it to sort months group.

Comment: I have inserted Matrix in ssrs .Then under column i gave data as 'Months'.Now the output columns are like  '' April | August | December | February |............|September. Means it is coming in sorted order from a-z. But I want that columns in normal form like January|February|March|......|December..

Comment: If your existing column contains Month name values (like January, February, etc.), but you want to sort chronologically instead of alphabetically, then this answer tells you a way to do that - add a field (calculated in SSRS or as part of the Dataset query which feeds your report) which maps the month names to numeric values, then sort on the new numeric field, while displaying the existing text field with the month names on your report.

Comment: This is the correct way. I got answer. Thank you :)